# Showing isomorphism between two groups (true or false question)

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I am asked if the group $\mathbb Q_+ = \{ q \in \mathbb Q\, | \,q >0 \} $  (under multiplication) is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ (under addition). How do I do this? I am just confused where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine there was an isomorphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. Then just as $1$ generates all of $\mathbb{Z}$, $\phi (1) = \frac{a}{b}$ would generate all of $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is clearly impossible (for example, it does not generate $\frac{a+1}{b}$).

Comment: Sorry, just confused. Why should $\frac{a}{b}$ generate all of $Q$?

Comment: @Ufomammut Jeffery is pointing out that $\mathbb{Z}$ has a generator (the number $1$), and the existence of a generator is invariant under isomorphism. In particular, if such an isomorphism existed, then $1$ would have to map to a generator of $\mathbb{Q}$, but the rationals do not have a generator so there can be no isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks a lot @BillWallis. Just completely forgot about that.

Comment: @Ufomammut: Since your question has been answered, do you like to accept the given answer? This way your question does not stay open indefinitely.

Comment: @Tortoise Thank you for reminding me.